# How do I increase the upload size only when editing special pages?

Tags: php, uploads, gallery, post-editor, plupload

I have the following code to increase the upload size only when editing certain, special pages:

```
function my_edit_page_form( $post ) {
    if( my_is_special_page( $post ) ) {
        add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'my_upload_size_limit' );
    }
}
add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'my_edit_page_form' );

function my_upload_size_limit( $size ) {
    return 1024 * 18000;
}
```

On one of those pages, I have a Gallery shortcode. When I click on the Edit button, the "Maximum upload" message looks correct, but the upload is denied:

[image: Maximum upload file size: 18 MB -- but 13 MB test.jpg exceeds the maximum upload size for this site.]

When viewing the source, I see that `max_file_size` set is to 8388608b, the default for the site. This value comes from [`wp_plupload_default_settings`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_plupload_default_settings/). This means this function must be called before the [`edit_page_form`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_page_form/) hook.

So, if I cannot use `edit_page_form`, what can I use instead that will be called before `wp_plupload_default_settings` in order to check the post? Or, alternatively, should I be checking the post from within [`upload_size_limit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_size_limit/)? If yes to the latter, then how do I do that?

-- UPDATE --

Here is my final code:

```
function my_upload_size_limit( $size ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post && $post->filter == 'edit' && $post->post_type == 'page' &&
        my_is_special_page( $post ) ) {
        $size = 1024 * 18000;
    }
    return $size;
}
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'my_upload_size_limit' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with your idea of checking if the right page is being viewed within the callback attached to the `upload_size_limit` hook.

This code demonstrates changing the upload size if one of the special pages is being viewed, and returning the standard max upload size otherwise:

```
function wpse239631_change_upload_size( $u_bytes, $p_bytes ) {
    // Array of post IDs where the upload size will be changed.
    $special_pages = array(
        1829, // change to your page
        1800, // change to your page, etc
    );

    // If we're on a special page, change the upload size,
    // otherwise, use the default max upload size.
    if ( in_array( get_the_ID(), $special_pages ) ) {
        return 1024 * 18000;
    } else {
        return min( $u_bytes, $p_bytes );
    }
}
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'wpse239631_change_upload_size', 10, 2 );
```